# Hibernate Explicit Polymorphism with JOINED Inheritence strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a base entity, with the following annotation based configuration:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BaseEntities")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "entityType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class BaseEntity { //...
```

And I have multiple child entities, each annotated with

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
@DiscriminatorValue("User")
@XmlRootElement
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class User extends BaseEntity { //...
```

(yes, there is Polymorphism annotation on all child entities and on the base entity as well)

But still, when I query a BaseEntity (f.e. with a Lazy loaded ManyToOne property), Hibernate joins (or, in this case, tries to join, but fails) all child entities - doesn't the PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT tells Hibernate to only load properties in the BaseEntity?

My persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="ebilling-backend" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://${database.location}:${database.port}/${database.dbname}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

How can I get Hibernate to recognize the Polymorphism annotation?
(note: the other JPA annotations are the basic javax.persistence annotations - can this be the problem?)

Or, the other way I thought of is to get Hibernate to use the DiscriminatorColumn, and only join that table, but how can I achieve this? (Without the Hibernate @Any - @AnyMetaDef annotations)

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is indeed misleading, but [ANN-314](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-314) JIRA issue explains what the Hibernate authors had in mind:

> Polymorphism explicit only applies on root entities and prevents queries naming a (unmapped) superclass to return mapped sub entities
>
> If the parent class was not mapped (e.g. being annotated with @Entity) and the sub-classes 
>   were having explicit polymorphism, then querying for super-class would not return the 
>   sub-class.

Comment: I see, thx. Is there any way to solve this problem? Leaving the BaseEntity in a separate DB table, and let it be queryable (without joining the child entities)?

Comment: I don't know of any such feature. You either use native SQL or remove inheritance from BaseEntity and simply use a ManyToOne association to a different entity hierarchy that supports inheritance. It's like adding an indirection layer.